# Sampler function not working with custom Color Kernels

Tags: swift, kernel, metal, core-image

Hello I've been struggling to get the sampler function working with custom Color Kernels. Below is what I've tried:

```
extern "C" { namespace coreimage {
float4 myColor3(sampler inputImage3, float firstpass) {
        
        float4 color = inputImage3.sample(inputImage3.coord());

        if (firstpass == 1){
            color.y = 1;    
        }
        
        return color;
        
    }
```

I get the following error message, where I load function from fromMetalLibraryData:
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError: file /Users/... line 163

Writing the kernel using sample_t works fine (no such error)... but I'm writing a filter that needs the coordinates of the current pixel (not yet implemented, just trying to get the kernel to run at all).

So my main question is why isn't sampler behaving like sample_t?

```
 float4 myColor3(sample_t inputImage3, float firstpass) {

        
        if (firstpass == 1){
            inputImage3.b = 1;            
        }
        return inputImage3;
        
    }
```

This is how I have the CIFilter set up:

```
 override var outputImage: CIImage? {

        guard let inputImage3 = inputImage3,
        let firstpass = firstpass
        else { return nil }
        
            return self.kernel3.apply(extent: inputImage3.extent, roiCallback: { _, rect -> CGRect in
                    return CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                                  width: rect.width,
                                  height: rect.height) },
                                       arguments: [inputImage3, firstpass])
```

**Edit:**

My .metal File (should it be named something else?)

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h> // includes CIKernelMetalLib.h

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

float4 myColor(constructors…){
…filter 1 
}

 float4 myColor2 (constructors…){
….filter 2
}
}}
```

Just how I setup my filter class for good measure:

```
class MetalFilter: CIFilter {

 var kernel: CIColorKernel
 var kernel2: CIColorKernel

  override init() { 
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        kernel = try! CIColorKernel(functionName: "myColor", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        kernel2 = try! CIColorKernel(functionName: "myColor2”, fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        super.init()
}
…
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you by chance using Xcode 12? How did you configure the Metal compiler for Core Image? I found a bug where, when using `metal` (instead of `metallib`) for linking CI kernels, functions that contain `samper` parameters won't get compiled into the resulting `metallib`. It works, however, when using `metallib` instead. Check out this year's WWDC session on building custom kernels in Metal. I also filed feedback for that (FB7795164).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for getting back so fast. I’m using Xcode 11.3… if I’m completely honest I don’t really know the difference between metal and metallib file (I’m pretty new to Swift and coding in general).
Here is the top of my .metal file: …see edited above

Comment: Also, on the WWDC talk they set up things quite different (custom build rules, etc)... I basically followed this tutorial but can see its a bit out of date:
https://medium.com/@shu223/core-image-filters-with-metal-71afd6377f4 
If nothing stands out to you as particularly wrong, I’ll try to match the WWDC setup (just am scared of breaking things).
Many thanks again.

Comment: Strange. The setup from the linked tutorial _should_ work in Xcode 11... Please keep us updated when you know more!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel) uses `sample_t` parameters [`CIKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel) uses `sampler` parameters. So trying in swift to load your kernel with wrong **kernel parameter types** will always return nil. This is because sampler is class with ability to address every pixel while sample_t is just a 4 float verctor containing color components of individual pixel. So you need to change you kernel type from [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel) to [`CIKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel).

I know that this is the very late answer but you should check the documentation for [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel).

Excerpt from documentation:

> It may use zero or more input images. Each input image is represented
> by a parameter of type **__sample** (Core Image Kernel Language) or
> **sample_t** (Metal Shading Language), **which can be treated as a single
> pixel color** of type vec4 (Core Image Kernel Language) or float4 (Metal
> Shading Language);.

This means that [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel) works with individual pixels from each image rather than with the whole image itself.

That is why general [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel) will look like this:

```
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" {
    namespace coreimage {
        float4 do_nothing(sample_t s) { // s - is a pixel of input image
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want to work with arbitraty pixels of your input image you should consider [`CIKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel) as more general class for image processing. As it is the most universal alternative of [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel)

Also from docs:

> It may use zero or more input images. Each input image is represented
> by a parameter of type sampler.

And probably the thing you looked for:

> A kernel routine typically **produces its output by calculating source
> image coordinates (using the destCoord and samplerTransform functions
> or the samplerTransform function)**, samples from the source images
> (**using the sample function**), and computes a final pixel color (output
> using the return keyword). For example, the Metal Shading Language
> source below implements a filter that passes through its input image
> unchanged.

Also example of such kernel:

```
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
 
extern "C" {
    namespace coreimage {
        float4 do_nothing(sampler src) {
            return src.sample(src.coord());
        }
    }
}
```

**So in sumary**:
If you want to process the whole image by performing sampling and other operations use [`CIKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel).
Otherwise if your custom filter uses both **color** and **geometry** information, **but does not require processing both at the same time**, you can improve performance by separating your image processing code: use a [`CIColorKernel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel) object for the color processing step and a CIWarpKernel object for the geometry processing step.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    float2 inputImage3Coord = inputImage.coord();
    float4 color = inputImage3.sample(inputImage3Coord);

    if (firstpass == 1){
        color.y = 1;    
    }
    
    return color;
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah, it's been a long time since I was doing Custom CIFilters.... I 'think' the issue was that I was using a CIColorKernel instead of using a CIKernel, all references I had seen suggested I could use the sampler function even with CIColorKernel... but I found I could not... the sample_t worked with color kernels (but I don't remember the difference anymore, something to do the coordinates)